# Check content function (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

I use the following function to check and display the content either in Dialog or Bottom Sheet, but when executing it does not work properly, as it displays both together, what is the reason and how can the problem be solved?

**Content function:**

```
content(BuildContext context, dynamic dialog, dynamic bottomSheet) {
  (MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.landscape) ? dialog : bottomSheet;
}
```

**Implementation:**

```
ElevatedButton(
    child: Text('Button'),
    onPressed: () {
        content(context, dialog(context), bottomSheet(context));
    }, 
),
```

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to determine the Orientation of the screen, we can use the OrientationBuilder Widget. The OrientationBuilder will determine the current Orientation and rebuild when the Orientation changes.

```
 void main() async {
  runApp(const Home(
  ));
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home:  Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child:  OrientationBuilder(
          builder: (context, orientation) {
            return ElevatedButton(
              child: Text('Button'),
              onPressed: () {
                revealContent(orientation,context);
              },
            );
          },
        )
      ),
    ));
  }
  revealContent(Orientation orientation, BuildContext context) {
     orientation == Orientation.landscape ? dialog(context) : bottomSheet(context);
  }
  dialog(BuildContext context){
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => const Dialog(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Text('test'),
          ),
        )
    );
  }
  bottomSheet(final BuildContext context)  {
    return showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      builder: (builder) => const Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Text('test'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

here are screenshots:

[image: Bottom Sheet in portrait mode]

[image: Dialog in landscape mode]

happy coding...

Comment: I'm already doing that, check the question again I've edited it

Comment: i've put screenshots and the code that i used in my answer

Comment: Hi bro, I already voted for you.

Comment: I do that bro .

Answer (score 0):

The reason the function is not working properly is because you're not actually showing the dialog or bottom sheet. To show the dialog or bottom sheet, you need to call showDialog or showModalBottomSheet, respectively, and pass them the result of calling dialog or bottomSheet.

try this

```js
void revealContent(BuildContext context, Widget dialog, Widget bottomSheet) {
  (MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.landscape)
      ? showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) => dialog)
      : showModalBottomSheet(context: context, builder: (context) => bottomSheet);

}
```

Comment: I already do this, and both the diallog and the bottomsheet appear on execution.
But the problem is that both appear at the same time

Comment: Check the question again, I edit it

Answer (score 0):

You have a fundamental misunderstanding as to what your code is doing.

Take your "Implementation" and `revealContent` code, for example:

```dart
ElevatedButton(
    child: Text('Button'),
    onPressed: () {
        revealContent(context, dialog(context), bottomSheet(context));
    }, 
),
```

```dart
revealContent(BuildContext context, dynamic dialog, dynamic bottomSheet) {
  (MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.landscape) ? dialog : bottomSheet;
}
```

You think that `revealContent` will invoke either `dialog` or `bottomSheet` based on the orientation of the screen. What you are actually doing, however, is you are **invoking both of them** and then **passing the result of the invocations** to `revealContent`, which isn't actually doing anything with them.

What you need to be doing is passing the functions as **callbacks** to `revealContent` and then invoking the callbacks within the function:

```dart
ElevatedButton(
    child: Text('Button'),
    onPressed: () {
        revealContent(context, () => dialog(context), () => bottomSheet(context));
    }, 
),
```

```dart
revealContent(BuildContext context, void Function() dialog, void Function() bottomSheet) {
  if (MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.landscape) {
    dialog()
  } else {
    bottomSheet();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be calling `showDialog` and `showModalBottomSheet` inside `revealContent`.

**Dialog**

```
dialog(BuildContext context){
 return Dialog( //.. );
}
```

**BottomSheet**

```
bottomSheet(final BuildContext context)  {
  return Widget( /.. );
}
```

**Reveal Content**

```
void revealContent(BuildContext context, Widget dialog, Widget bottomSheet) {
  if (MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.landscape) {
      return showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) => dialog);
  } else {
      return showModalBottomSheet(context: context, builder: (context) => bottomSheet);
  } 

}
```